# User permissions to objects with NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, permissions

Say you have the three following tables, with the important comlumns listed:

Users: user_id
Entities: entity_id
Events: event_id, entity_id
UserEntityPermissions: user_id, entity_id, is_admin

Now when a user requests access to view an event or a list of events given some set of search parameters, I want to make sure that the user only can view events for entities that they have been permissioned on. Are there any facilities in NHibernate to do that?

Additionally, there is another level of permissioning which is even more complex, where events can be associated with additional objects, let's call them Locations:
Locations: location_id
EventLocations: event_id, location_id
UserLocationPermissions: user_id, location_id

In this case, users who are not admins for an entity should only be able to view events where they have permissions to all of the linked locations. It seems like once I start adding those types of permissions, adding any filters to the query of the events gets completely unmanageable.

What pattern would you use to simplify the middle layer to make sure that users only have access to events they should see?

Would you always return all of the events from the database to the middle tier and then check each event to see if the user has permissions? It seems like there would be a huge amount of overhead to do that.

Answer (score 0):

1. I know of nothing that makes it so automatically in NHibernate.
2. I do not know if your project is possible using queries using lambda
   expression (or Criteria), if so I would build an abstraction layer
   that add filters on all queries on the entities that inherit. So
   that logic would need to be applied only once.

> Ps: It's just a hint of implementation.